# Let $A, B$ and $C$ be $n × n$ matrices such that $ABC = I_n$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Among the following equations, which are true, which are not necessarily true? Justify your answer.

(1) $ACB = I_n$,
(2) $BAC = I_n$,
(3) $BCA = I_n$,
(4) $CAB = I_n$,
(5) $CBA = I_n$.
Hint: The counterexamples can be found among $2 × 2$ matrices

I'm thinking that none are true because matrix multiplication is not commutative... However, this does not seem right.

Comment: You should know that if $AB=I_n$ for $A,B\in k^{n\times n}$, then $BA=I_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) does not hold: let $A=I_n$ and $B, C$ non-commuting.

(2) does not hold: let $C=I_n$ and $A, B$ non-commuting.

(3) does not hold: let $B=I_n$ and $A, C$ non-commuting.

(4) holds: $C$ is the inverse of $AB$, so they commute.

(5) does not hold: let $C=I_n$ and $A, B$ non-commuting.